# CS-Cart. Как правильно добавлять товар через API с указанием характеристик и вариций?

Tags: php, cs-cart

Есть необходимость добавить на сайт товар через API CS-Cart, нашел вот такую документацию: [ссылка](https://www.cs-cart.ru/docs/4.10.x/developer_guide/api/entities/products.html)

Попробовал просто добавить товар указав ему название, цену, и id категории. Все получилось хорошо.

Вопрос: как указать товару заранее созданную характеристику, а если такой характеристики ещё нет, то создать её? И как добавлять этому же товару вариации?

Пробовал вот так:

> product=test&price=100&category_ids[]=367&product_features[]=551
> но характеристика не применилась

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Документация действительно не сильно подробная, но если верить интуиции. Похоже что в теле POST запроса на `features` можно указать поле `parent_id` которое должно быть идентификатором `products`. Тем самым связав продукт с фичей.

Comment: вот в этой части документации https://www.cs-cart.ru/docs/4.10.x/developer_guide/api/#id14 как раз говорится про вложенность сущностей правда, не нашел диаграммы с полной описанием всей модели

Answer (score 1):

В процессе поиска ответа и добавления комментариев. Нашел полный вариант документации который описывает ваш кейс.

1. Пример добавление [товара с характеристикой](https://docs.cs-cart.com/latest/developer_guide/api/entities/product_features.html#working-with-the-features-of-a-product)

   ```
   curl -X POST "http://example.com/api/products" 
   -H "Content-type: application/json"
   -H "Authorization: Basic ******" 
   -d '{"product": "New Product", "category_ids": "223", "main_category": "223", "price": "10", "status": "A", "product_features": {"23": {"feature_type": "T", "value": "Test"}}}'
   ```

2. Пример связывания [продукта и группы вариации](https://docs.cs-cart.com/latest/developer_guide/api/entities/product_variations.html#creating-updating-products)

   ```
   curl -X PUT "http://example.com/api/product_variations/:id" 
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
   -H "Authorization: Basic ******" 
   -d '{"variation_group_id":11}'
   ```

или создание продукта и одновременное добавление его в группу вариации

```
curl -X POST "http://example.com/api/product_variations_groups/:code/product_variations" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-H "Authorization: Basic ******" 
-d '{"product":"Pants","price":150,"product_features":{"549":1199,"548":1195},"category_ids":[224]}'
```

Тут ссылка на создание [групп вариации](https://docs.cs-cart.com/latest/developer_guide/api/entities/product_variation_groups.html#create-a-variation-group)

Надеюсь это вам поможет. Нашел документацию через [репозитории](https://github.com/cscart)

Comment: но здесь просто добавление товара с характеристикой, а как еще добавить вариации к этому товару?

Comment: @iKey обновил ответ, не стал полность дублировать все из документации, привел основные примеры и ссылки на них. Мне кажется там более полно и ясно все это описано